# TinyMCE 4 Take over classname of textarea to tinymce container

Tags: javascript, css, validation, tinymce-4, classname

I have a classname on my textarea when the input isn't valid, normally it gives the textarea a red border, but when i use TinyMCE with the textarea as editor, the TinyMCE container doesn't get a red border because it's not taking over the textarea's classname. Is there a way to do that in TinyMCE in combination with JavaScript?

Comment: I have tried to create a callback function with `init_instance_callback` that when a new editor gets initialized it gets the attribute class name and takes it over, but when the editor gets initialized it appears that the class name not exists, but it's strange because i can get the id of the editor.